# How should implement an migration to replace an enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I already have this enum

```
class RenameSalaryTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :salaries
      create_enum :salary_types, %w[very_good is_medium too_low BAD]
      t.enum :salary_type, index: true, enum_type: 'salary_types'
    end
  end
end
```

i would like to replace with this enum in other migration

```
:salary_types, %w[good medium low bad]
```

how can i implement a migration to replace it?

Comment: Please be nice by not deleting your questions when they are answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76599747/in-my-db-i-have-stored-any-card-debit-card-but-i-am-returning-as-card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Rails 7.0 you can add below migration to rename enum value

```
class RenameSalaryTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TYPE salary_types RENAME VALUE "very_good" TO "good"
      ALTER TYPE salary_types RENAME VALUE "is_medium" TO "medium"
      ALTER TYPE salary_types RENAME VALUE "too_low" TO "low"
      ALTER TYPE salary_types RENAME VALUE "BAD" TO "bad"
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TYPE salary_types RENAME VALUE "good" TO "very_good"
      ALTER TYPE salary_types RENAME VALUE "medium" TO "is_medium"
      ALTER TYPE salary_types RENAME VALUE "low" TO "too_low"
      ALTER TYPE salary_types RENAME VALUE "bad" TO "BAD"
    SQL
  end
end
```

Recently [PR#44898](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/44898) got merged in rails main branch which will migration helper added PG enum drop, rename, add value, rename value. Once this PR is released above migration can be written as below.

```
class RenameSalaryTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    rename_enum_value :salary_types, from: "very_good", to: "good"
    rename_enum_value :salary_types, from: "is_medium", to: "medium"
    rename_enum_value :salary_types, from: "too_low", to: "low"
    rename_enum_value :salary_types, from: "BAD", to: "bad"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the `activerecord-postgres_enum` gem, you first need to add the new enum values using `add_enum_value`, then you'll translate existing enums over from old value to new value, and then you'll remove the old values using `remove_enum_value`.  Docs here: https://github.com/bibendi/activerecord-postgres_enum#usage